# How do I find the Sum of the two cards dealt?

Tags: arrays, ruby, sum

I have everything working just having trouble pulling out the values of the cards dealt.

```
class Card
  attr_accessor :rank, :suit, :value

  def initialize (rank, suit, value)
    @rank = rank
    @suit = suit
    @value = value
  end

  def to_s
    "The #{rank} of #{suit} is #{value}"
  end
end

class Deck
  RANK_VALUE = [2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 10, 10, 10, 11]
  RANKS = ['2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', '10', 'J', 'Q', 'K', 'A']
  SUITS = ['Clubs', 'Diamonds', 'Spades', 'Hearts']

  def initialize
    @cards = []
    RANKS.each_with_index do |rank, index|
      value = RANK_VALUE[index]
        SUITS.each do |suit|
          @cards << Card.new(rank, suit, value)
        end
    end
  end

  def shuffle
    @cards.shuffle!
  end

  def deal
    @cards.pop(2) #how to sum the two cards here?
  end


end


deck = Deck.new
deck.shuffle
puts deck.deal
```

Should I put values into an array and sum the array?

Comment: Can you make the question a bit more clear?

Comment: If you need the sum of rank values, you can do: `@cards.pop(2).sum(&:value)`

Comment: as a note `:rank, :suit, :value` should be `readers` (not `accessors`) so that I can't change pocket 2s into pocket Aces :)

Answer (score 2):

A short and direct solution:

```
@cards.map(&:value).sum
```

If you simply want to convert an array of cards into values, can obviously leave off the sum, and can get an array of values simply using `map`.

```
@cards.map(&:value)
```

Comment: `['2', '3'].sum` raises `TypeError (String can't be coerced into Integer)`

Comment: Yeah, should have been `value`, not `rank`. Corrected my answer, thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: we could also define a coercion on `Card` such that `def coerce(other); [value,other]; end;` results in `@cards.sum`